# Mass Storage USB pack of Keil uVision5

Tags: keil, usb-mass-storage

I'm using USB device-Mass Storage template of Keil uVision5 but when I run it (on board),I can't access the SD card and PC just detects that a device is connected to USB. I commented **check_media** function.(Because SD card detect pin is available in my board). my microcontroller is NXP LPC1768. what's wrong?

Comment: in the question there is no information at all to help you. what you mean with 'i can't access the sd card'? you get access denied? the system does not detects it? any error? any code?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.I mean that PC don't detect it as Mass Storage device, It just detect a Removable Disk connected. I can't read,write or create a file in SD card. the program compiled with out any error. I didn't change the template code except check_media function.(In user manual explained that if check media is available omit it. )

Comment: You need to post more context, more info about what you've tried, which errors you get etc. and you probably need to post some code as well. FYI questions about debugging embedded code is not the most active niche here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved :D
I changed RTE_Device.h configuration file.